# What is the best order to declare things in the head?

Tags: jquery, html, head, scrollreveal.js

In a HTML document, what is the best practice when arranging the various CDN's and references?

In a website I am building I am referencing jQuery, css, font awesome, scroll reveal as well as external HTML files that contain the header and footer.

What's prompted me to ask this question is on this webpage I am creating, the "About Us" header flickers before the scroll reveal has taken place, and I wondered if that was down the the order in which I declare things in the head.

http://mi-linux.wlv.ac.uk/~1403809/AcademyWebsite/aboutUs.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>About Us</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<link rel="icon" href="images/whiteFww1.png">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>


<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#header1").load("header1.html");
        $("#footer").load("footer.html");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The flickering is nothing to do with the order scripts load. It's because you're making an AJAX request to retrieve that HTML. This means that you need to wait for: 1) jQuery to be loaded 2) the DOM to be ready 3) the AJAX request to complete 4) the HTML to be injected in to the page. This is why client-side includes are, generally speaking, a bad idea. If you want to include common content in to pages do it server side. Then you will have absolutely none of this overhead on the client.

Comment: You are actually loading both the header and the footer twice.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Are CDN's examples of Client-Side includes?

Comment: @LucaKiebel Please explain

Comment: Yes, indeed they are, but not relevant to the issue you have loading the `header1.html` and `footer.html`. By client side includes I mean injecting HTML in to the page. Not including other JS scripts. I'd suggest you Google 'server side include [your server language here]' for a better understanding of what you need to do

Comment: Load your page and take a look at the Network tab of the dev tools. You are loading both `header1.html` and `footer.html` twice: https://i.stack.imgur.com/niu7f.jpg

Comment: Client-side includes are when you do something like `$("#header1").load("header1.html")`. You could have merged the header and footer into `aboutUs.html` on the server.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Can you see why that's happening? He only calls `.load()` once for each.

Comment: It seems like the code to load the files is in the header once in a script (like shown here) and once in http://mi-linux.wlv.ac.uk/~1403809/AcademyWebsite/js/script.js

Comment: Assumes like loader is not issue, its due to parent element % height, please check with a pixel value and check issue persists.... .landingImage1 {height:50%; ....}

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the flickering, it's due to the Ajax .load calls you are making. But in terms of how you should order your scripts, usually you want the local scripts to be run first, the CDN's are usually kept as a backup if the local's can't load.

Your main script should be in your body, this is because the functionality in your main script would usually be dependent on the DOM. (This should help with the flickering issue)

Jquery should always be after the meta tags but before any script that would need access to Jquery.

Hope that helps!